# foreach loop eats data

Tags: php, loops

I have the following code and output. How is this possible that after the loop note #2 is overwritten with the data of note #1?

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>".print_r($notes, true)."</pre>";

    foreach($notes as $k=>$note){
        // nothing here
    }

    echo "<pre>".print_r($notes, true)."</pre>";
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2015-11-17 13:22:19
            [user] => 249340
            [text] => test
            [important] =>
            [author] => Joe
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2015-11-17 12:52:44
            [user] => 249340
            [text] => He is Spanish
            [important] =>
            [author] => Bill
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2015-11-17 12:52:28
            [user] => 249340
            [text] => He is a clown
            [important] => 1
            [firstname] => Bill
        )

)

Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2015-11-17 13:22:19
            [user] => 249340
            [text] => test
            [important] =>
            [author] => Joe
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2015-11-17 12:52:28
            [user] => 249340
            [text] => He is a clown
            [important] => 1
            [firstname] => Bill
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [created] => 2015-11-17 12:52:28
            [user] => 249340
            [text] => He is a clown
            [important] => 1
            [author] => Bill
        )

)
```

The code defining `$notes`:

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user=249340";
    $select = $mysqli->query($query);

    while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc()) {
        $notes[$row['id']] = array_filter($row,function($var){return
!is_null($var);});
        unset($notes[$row['id']]["id"]);
    }
    $select->free();

    if(!count($notes)) {
        $notes = NULL;
    }

    krsort($notes);
?>
```

Comment: In the documentation comments http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php there are a couple of references to unexpected behaviour of the array pointer after such an interation - see the second user note plus a few others shortly after that.  That could be your issue?

Comment: So, I tried it, but it gives the exact result which it should.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Just updated my question with the preceeding code.

Comment: @WindsorAndy let me try this, maybe that's the clue